# Shall I use solid state relay to switch DC supply?

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay

What is the best way to switch the DC supply of a device (5V/2A)? Is it against some safety standard to use a mechanical latching switch on the supply line directly, or shall I use a SSR to switch the supply, and use the mechanical switch only to apply the control signal to the SSR?

I understand that for higher voltages and currents it's generally a good idea to use a SSR. But is it also recommended in my case?

Comment: Switching 5 V DC isn't a particularly unsafe thing to do, unless there's something about your application where other issues are involved. What's being powered?

Comment: What do you mean, what can cause a problem? I have an analog circuitry working on an incoming signal, ADCs, DACs, a microcontroller.

Comment: The world is full of devices that switch far higher currents and voltages than that with mechanical switches. Other systems may be used for safety reasons (e.g. machinery) or in hazardous environments where a spark might ignite something, or underwater,  but I'm struggling to see what makes you think it's a problem in your application.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'm not foreseeing any problem. But I've been wrong before, this is why I am asking others whether it could cause a problem, and / or if there is some safety standard prescribing that I should not do it.

But apparently, I should just proceed it with the switch then.